# Please save me... iFrame Grid Positioning not working

Tags: html, css, iframe

[image: this is how it is overlapping]I am trying to create this website for my friends squarespace website. I am having trouble positioning this video in my grid... can someone help? It keeps overlaying over other content... not sure what to do. It either overlays with other content, or cuts/crops the video. I just want a very simple layout, all of the elements centered cascading down the page. I am not sure if its better to use flex box or grid... but the iframe is proving to be a problem. I want to make it responsive, which is why my CSS is the way it is... do I need to use media queries to fix this?

CSS:

```
 .container{
 display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;

}
.musicvideo {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (divide 9 by 16 = 0.5625) */
  margin: -1px
  display:grid;
    grid-row: 5 / 10;
}

/* Then style the iframe to fit in the container div with full height and width */
.iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
    grid-row: 5 / 10;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="musicvideo">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_AUP9FVIYl4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @Hypermystic I added the screenshot! Please let me know if you have any advice ><

Comment: Is this something you are looking for. I am not sure about the exact CSS of yours but the functionality you require can be achieved using https://jsbin.com/huwomufaso/1/edit?html,css,output

Reference: https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-make-a-responsive-100-width-youtube-iframe-embed